# Multilingual Profile Center

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does the native Marketing Cloud Profile Center page allow for a multilingual experience. For example, if a subscriber has a language preference of French, they would be directed to the French Profile Center page based on their language preference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:** Yes it does.

**Explanation:**

By Default, Marketing Cloud passes the language of the user's browser into the profile center, so the profile center will always be displayed in the user's language.

I have found that most time, brands do not want to use the default profile centers and go for custom landing pages. You can achieve language personalization by one of the two options:

1. You can either build multiple cloud pages / microsites for the different languages, then at within your ampscript logic, have the Concat function pull the subscriber's language from a data extension and direct them to the appropriate page.
2. You can pass the subscriber language into the Microsite or CloudPagesURL function. Then within the body of your landing page, use the combination of a translation table and the language column (Retrieve from the query string with the RequestParameter function) to change language.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A little addition: This only applies to a custom profile center, but I guess the question is related to the standard one.

Comment: Missed that will update

Answer (score 1):

The default profile center is automatically displayed in the language of the user's browser. So it is multi lingual by default. However, I don't know of a possibility to explicitly set the language the Profile Center is displayed in.

To explicitly set the language a custom Profile Center would be the best option I guess (have a look at Data_Kid's answer for two possible options). Flexibility wise I think a custom profile center is the best option for most setups.